# Widget which adjusts to the children size?

Tags: flutter, overflow, flutter-layout

Is there a widget in Flutter which adjusts itself on the content of it's children which are in Rows and Columns?

I can't seem to find anything related, and I am constantly hit with infinite overflows errors.....

As an example, lets say I would have 3 Widgets in a Row, 1 of which is a text, which I cannot guess how long it will be, but I need to expand the parent as much as the widget needs and at the sametime wrap the text

I would have something like:

```
Row(
children: [
Expanded(child: Widget1(....)),
Expended(child: Text(.....)),
Expanded(child: Widget2(....))
]
)
```

Right?

I would want the parent of the row to expand as much as it needs for the children to be shown, I want to align Widget1 and Widget2 in different ways (1-center, 2-bottom).
If I put them in Column I can center Widget1, but I cannot put Widget2 at the bottom because if I put Column to max size it overflows, if I don't it doesn't align...

How would you do it?

I really don't understand the logic behind the inifnite layout thing....

For example, here is where I am stuck at the moment.

```
return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Global.findCategory(event.categId).color.withAlpha(150),
                    blurRadius: 20,
                    spreadRadius: -20,
                    offset: Offset(0, 5)
                )
              ],
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Container(
                      width: Global.scaleSmallDevice(context) * 64,
                      height: Global.scaleSmallDevice(context) * 64,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: event.image
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                )
                ,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomText(
                      text: title,
                      color: Global.findCategory(event.categId).color,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: CustomText(
                        text: shortInfo,
                        color: Global.findCategory(event.categId).color,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (context, setState) {
                        IconData buttonIcon = (event.favorite) ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border;
                        return SplashButton(
                            splashColor: Global.findCategory(event.categId).color,
                            child: Icon(buttonIcon, color: Global.findCategory(event.categId).color, size: 30),
                            onTap: () async {
                              await event.setFavorite(context);
                              setState(() {
                                buttonIcon = (event.favorite) ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border;
                              });
                            }
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

In this case I want the StatefulBuilder widget to be on the bottom and the entire container be as small as the column with the CustomText widgets.

The widget with image inside I want it to be centered, while the text to be fully available to the user.

If I don't add a Column as Container, it goes as the height allows it and the StatefulBuilder widget center itself at the bottom, in the curent code it's at the center.....

Sorry if I'm not coherent, it's a bit late and I am tired after coding all day and stuck at this widget for a few hours.

Comment: Do you need a layout like, Widget1 on top and both Text and widget2 at bottom?

Comment: Can you share the code in the case it overflows?

Comment: Is the `Align` widget what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/SupposedlySam/pen/gOaGbzX

Comment: I have added the code which bugs me at the moment and what I am trying to achieve, hope it clarifies more, thank you.